# I have configured Selenium Cucumber Maven project and getting Initialization error while executing my runner.TestRunnerTest_Test.java file

Tags: selenium, cucumber

I am new to Selenium Cucumber Maven integration. 
I am using Cucumber 3.0.2 . My TestRunnerTest code is given below :

```
package runner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.cli.Main;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(

    glue= {"stepDefinition"} ,
    plugin={"html:reports/report"} 
            , features = "features" 
            ,  tags= {"@Valid or @Invalid or emptyCredentials"}
       )
public class TestRunnerTest {
public static WebDriver driver; 
private static TestRunnerTest sharedInstance = new TestRunnerTest();
public static TestRunnerTest getInstance() {
        return sharedInstance;
    }

  @BeforeClass
    public static void before() {   
      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
"E:\\ChromeDriverNew\\chromedriver.exe");
           driver=new ChromeDriver(); 
           driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
    @AfterClass
    public static void after() {    
         Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread()
            {
                  @Override
                public void run()
                  {         
                    try {
                    Files.move(Paths.get("reports/report"), Paths.get("reports/report_"+ 
                    LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYYLd_HHmmss"))), 
                                StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                      }
                   }
              });
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

And my feature file is given below :

Feature: Test Login page

```
Scenario: Verify whether user is able to redirect to the Home URL
When I go to "https://abcd/home"

@Valid
Scenario: Verify whether user is able to Login with valid Email and Password
When I go to "/login"
 And I enter username "" 
 And I enter password ""
 And I click on submit
```

Also my baseDefinition file is given :

```
package stepDefinition;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
import runner.TestRunnerTest;
import support.Locators;
import support.TestData;

public class baseDefinition {
public Boolean beforsuit=true;
public String baseurl = "https://abcd.in";
private static TestRunnerTest runner_TestObj = TestRunnerTest.getInstance();
public  WebDriver driver = runner_TestObj.driver;   

@When("^I go to \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void i_go_to(String url) {
    driver.get(baseurl+url);
}
@When("^I enter username \"([^\"]*)\$")
public void i_enter_in(String arg1) {
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys(email);
}
@When("^I enter password \"([^\"]*)\$")
public void i_enter_in(String arg1) {
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(pass);
}
@When("^I click on submit$")
public void i_click_on(String arg1) {
   driver.findElement(By.id("submitbutton")).click();
}
```

After running this as Maven Test, I am getting this error :

```
-------------------------------------------------------
T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running runner.TestRunnerTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.55 sec <<< 
FAILURE!
initializationError(runner.TestRunnerTest)  Time elapsed: 0.031 sec  <<< 
ERROR!
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: 
Illegal repetition near index 7
I enter {string} is present
   ^
at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend.addStepDefinition(JavaBackend.java:156)
at cucumber.runtime.java.MethodScanner.scan(MethodScanner.java:68)
at cucumber.runtime.java.MethodScanner.scan(MethodScanner.java:41)
at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend.loadGlue(JavaBackend.java:86)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:92)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:70)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:66)
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.createRuntime(Cucumber.java:80)
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:59)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

I am new to this cucumber-selenium framework and not understanding where i am going wrong.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you really have twice the method `public void i_enter_in(String arg1)` in the same class file? Try to comment out all glue methods and run your test. Cucumber by default will complain about the missed methods and print the correct signature it is looking for.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have updated file and re-run. But still getting this initialization error .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text in your error message `I enter {string} is present` seems not to be linked to the code you posted. Try first with a stripped down example and expand it when you got it running.

Find a simplified example based on the code you posted below.

Assuming you have following dependencies in the `pom.xml`

```
<properties>
    <version.cucumber>3.0.2</version.cucumber>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>${version.cucumber}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${version.cucumber}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and only the two following files

**src/test/java/features/login-page.feature**

```
Feature: cucumber

  Scenario: Verify whether user is able to redirect to the Home URL
    When I go to "https://abcd/home"

  Scenario: Verify whether user is able to Login with valid Email and Password
    When I go to "/login"
    And I enter username "user"
    And I enter password "password"
    And I click on submit
```

**src/test/java/runner/TestRunnerTest.java**

```
package runner;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/java/features/login-page.feature",
        glue = { "stepDefinition" }
        )
public class TestRunnerTest {
}
```

running the test with `mvn compile test` will produce the following output

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running runner.TestRunnerTest

Undefined scenarios:
src/test/java/features/login-page.feature:3 # Verify whether user is able to redirect to the Home URL
src/test/java/features/login-page.feature:6 # Verify whether user is able to Login with valid Email and Password

2 Scenarios (2 undefined)
5 Steps (5 undefined)
0m0.079s


You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

@When("I go to {string}")
public void i_go_to(String string) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@When("I enter username {string}")
public void i_enter_username(String string) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@When("I enter password {string}")
public void i_enter_password(String string) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@When("I click on submit")
public void i_click_on_submit() {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

copy the missing steps methods into your `src/test/java/stepDefinition/baseDefinition.java` and run the test again. The test will fail with following error.

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running runner.TestRunnerTest

Pending scenarios:
src/test/java/features/login-page.feature:3 # Verify whether user is able to redirect to the Home URL
src/test/java/features/login-page.feature:6 # Verify whether user is able to Login with valid Email and Password

2 Scenarios (2 pending)
5 Steps (3 skipped, 2 pending)
0m0.028s

cucumber.api.PendingException: TODO: implement me
    at stepDefinition.baseDefinition.i_go_to(baseDefinition.java:34)
    at ✽.I go to "https://abcd/home"(src/test/java/features/login-page.feature:4)

cucumber.api.PendingException: TODO: implement me
    at stepDefinition.baseDefinition.i_go_to(baseDefinition.java:34)
    at ✽.I go to "/login"(src/test/java/features/login-page.feature:7)

Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 2, Time elapsed: 0.474 sec
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This solution has solved my issue